# Using grep with ps -ax to kill numerous applications at once (Mac)

Tags: bash, shell, unix, grep, kill

I'm very new to shell scripting. I recently covered a tutorial of using bash with grep.

About 5 minutes ago there was, as it happened, a practical application for this function as my browser appeared to have crashed. I wanted to, for practice, use the shell to find the process and then kill it.

I typed `ps -ax | grep Chrome`

But many lines appeared with lots of numbers on the left (are these "job numbers" or "process numbers"?)

Is there a way to Kill all "jobs" where Chrome exists in the name of the process? Rather than kill each one individually?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I do not recommend using `killall`.
And you should NOT use `-9` at first.

I recommend a simple `pkill`:

```
pkill Chrome
```

Comment: I tried that and was told "command not found" then the following kill: usage: kill [-s sigspec | -n signum | -sigspec] pid | jobspec ... or kill -l [sigspec]
I'm using a Mac if that makes a difference (I'm very new to the differences of Unix and LInux and don;t even know if that's relevant. Thanks all the same

Comment: Then install the `proctools` package (http://sourceforge.net/projects/proctools/) or try with the other solutions. And yes, if you are using MacOSX there is some differences with the `coreutils` and all the built-in commands. The next time try to specify it in the tags.

Answer (score 2):

You can use killall:

```
killall Chrome
```

Edit: Removed "-9" since it should be used as a last resource (was: killall -9 Chrome).

Comment: Do not use `kill -9`. The default of sending a TERM signal should be sufficient.

Comment: @chepner: +1 for this... I see all too often the '-9' : it should ONLY be used when the regular kill doesn't work, as it doesn't let the app "clean after it" properly (nor close file descriptors, etc)

Answer (score 2):

I like my solution better. Because adds a kind of wildcard to it. I did this:

```
mkdir ~/.bin

echo "ps -ef | grep -i $1 | grep -v grep | awk '{print $2}' | xargs kill -9" > ~/.bin/k

echo "alias k='/Users/YOUR_USER_HERE/.bin/k $1'" >> ~/.profile

chmod +x ~/.bin/k
```

Now to kill stuff you type:

```
k Chrome
```

or

```
k chrome
```

or

```
k chr
```

Just be careful with system processes or not to be killed processes.

Like if you have Calculator running and another one called Tabulator also running. If you type
`k ulator` it will kill'em both.

Also remember that this will kill ALL instances of the program(s) that match the variable after the command `k`.

Because of this, you can create two aliases inside your profile file and make 2 files inside .bin one with the command `grep -i` and the other without it. The one without the -i flag will be case and name sensitive.